# count number of available in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a question in mysql php please help

I have the following table (users) :

```
id    name 
------------
1     test     
2     test2
3     test3
4     test4
5     test5
```

Another table called (qty) :

```
id   user_id  available
-----------------------
1      1         1
2      1         1
3      2         0
4      2         1
5      3         0
6      4         0
```

what I need to count how many are available (1) and also show the ones that are not available:

Output like :

```
user_name   count_available
----------------------------
test          2
test2         1
test3         0
test4         0
test5         0
```

Could this be done in one SQL statement and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an aggregation and a left join:

```
select u.name, sum(q.available) as count_available
from users u left join
     qty q
     on u.id = q.user_id
group by u.name;
```

Comment: @user3150060 . . . It strike me that this might return NULL instead of 0.  To fix that, use `coalesce(sum(q.available), 0)`.

Comment: it didnt return NULL at my end